# Typescript implement interface strictly

Tags: typescript, types, interface

```
interface User {
  email: string;
}

interface UserDoc extends User, Document {
}

type someFunc = () => User;
```

How can I make sure that someFunc returns exactly User but not UserDoc or any other implementations/extensions of User?

Comment: Im not quiet sure if i understand your question may u can be more explicit about your question?